# Error with DbSeed-Migration in WebApiBackend (netcore2)

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, backend, webapi

I have an WebApi Backend with the following strucutre:
[image]

In the database library I have a CSV file. In the DbSeeder.cs class I want to fill my database.

The CSV structure looks like:

```
DayOfWeek;Starter;MainCourse;Dessert;Price
Montag;Tagessuppe;Kaiserschmarrn mit Apfelmus;;4.50
Dienstag;;Cordon bleu mit Kartoffeln und Salat;Dessert;4.20
Mittwoch;Tagessuppe;Geschnetzeltes mit Erbsenreis;;4.90
Donnerstag;;Burger mit Wedges;Dessert;6.30
Freitag;Tagessuppe;Eiernockerl mit Salat;;3.90
```

As you can see not every field in this file has a value but this is not the problem.
The real problem is in my DbSeeder.cs class I think.

```
public static class DbSeeder
    {
        public static FoodOrderBackendContext Seed(FoodOrderBackendContext db)
        {
            db.Meals.AddRange(
                File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\floha\Desktop\Essensbestellungen\Backend\FoodOrderBackend\FoodOrderBackendDb\meals.csv")
                .Select(x =>
                {
                    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(x);
                    builder.Replace(";;", ";-;");
                    string newX = builder.ToString();
                    var s = newX.Split(';');
                    string weekday = s[0];
                    int weekNr = 0;
                    switch (weekday)
                    {
                        case "Montag":
                            weekNr = 1;
                            break;
                        case "Dienstag":
                            weekNr = 2;
                            break;
                        case "Mittwoch":
                            weekNr = 3;
                            break;
                        case "Donnerstag":
                            weekNr = 4;
                            break;
                        case "Freitag":
                            weekNr = 5;
                            break;
                        case "Samstag":
                            weekNr = 6;
                            break;
                        case "Sonntag":
                            weekNr = 7;
                            break;
                    }
                    return new Meal()
                    {
                       Weekday = weekNr,
                       Starter = s[1],
                       MainCourse = s[2],
                       Dessert= s[3],
                       Price=float.Parse(s[3])
                    };
                })
                .AsEnumerable());
            db.SaveChanges();
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Here is also a code snippet of my Meal.cs class:

```
public partial class Meal
    {
        public Meal()
        {
            Orders = new HashSet<Order>();
        }

        public int MealId { get; set; }
        public int Weekday { get; set; }
        public string Starter { get; set; }
        public string MainCourse { get; set; }
        public string Dessert { get; set; }
        public float Price { get; set; }

        public ICollection<Order> Orders { get; set; }
    }
```

With `Add-Migration Seed` I created a migration, where I want to call this DbSeeder.Seed(db) method.

```
public partial class Seed : Migration
    {
        FoodOrderBackendContext db;
        protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {
            DbSeeder.Seed(db);
        }

        protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {

        }
    }
```

Now when I want to execute the Update-Database Command, the following error is showing up:
[image]
Does someone of you know what the error could mean? Or a solution.

ErrorText:

The EF Core tools version '2.1.1-rtm-30846' is older than that of the runtime '2.1.11-servicing-32099'. Update the tools for the latest features and bug fixes.
Applying migration '20200507182207_Seed'.
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at FoodOrderBackendDb.DbSeeder.Seed(FoodOrderBackendContext db) in C:\Users\floha\Desktop\Essensbestellungen\Backend\FoodOrderBackend\FoodOrderBackendDb\DbSeeder.cs:line 13
   at FoodOrderBackendDb.Migrations.Seed.Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder) in C:\Users\floha\Desktop\Essensbestellungen\Backend\FoodOrderBackend\FoodOrderBackendDb\Migrations\20200507182207_Seed.cs:line 10
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Migration.BuildOperations(Action`1 buildAction)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Migration.<.ctor>b__4_1()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.LazyRef`1.get_Value()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Migration.get_UpOperations()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.Migrator.GenerateUpSql(Migration migration)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.Migrator.<>c__DisplayClass13_2.b__2()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.Migrator.Migrate(String targetMigration)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.UpdateDatabase(String targetMigration, String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabase.<>c__DisplayClass0_1.<.ctor>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: Could you paste the error as text? That would make it easier to read and make it searchable

Comment: i added the error as text now. @devNull

Comment: In your `Seed` class, you pass `db` to `DbSeeder.Seed` without initializing it. Unless your initializing the context somewhere else, that'd be what's causing the null reference

Comment: You might need to do something similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46011243/5803406)

Comment: so what do I have to change in my code then? I am a little bit confused @devNull

Comment: if you take a look at the answer in the post I just linked, you'll need to use the `DbMigrationsConfiguration<>` class to seed the values using your DbContext